# overloading operator >>, passing one parameter to object instead of 3

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, cin, istream

I have an object "d" of type Date. I am trying to use an overloading operator to take in only one parameter from the user instead  of the three that the objects has. In other words, I want the program to be able to take input from the user and be able to only change the "month_" data member and then having that data member be passed to the "incMon()" so that the month and the year adjust accordingly to however many months the user wants to increment the date using only the "month_" data member.

How can I adjust the overloading operator and incMon() to allow this process to happen?

This is what I have.

```
void Date::read(istream & is)
    {
        unsigned month;

        is >> month;

        month_ = month;

    }


    istream & operator>>(istream & is, Date & d)
    {
        d.read(is);
        return is;
    }
```

Comment: Well, actually I don't understand why you need a Date parameter for IncrementMonth?

Comment: It is part of my requirement. If I didn't need that date parameter things would have been a lot easier.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify what `incrementMonth` should do, as you don't use the parameter. Does it modify the parameter or `*this` or both? What are the expected values of `d1` and `d2` after you say `d1.incrementMonth(d2, 1)`? (My guess is that `d2` is left unmodified and `d1` contains the date resulting from incrementing `d2` by one month, but that's just a guess.)

Comment: Im sorry. I just didnt know how to implement it and call it. The function takes two parameters and increment the date so if the date was 01-01-2000 (month-day-year) and the user increments it 13 months, then the output should be (02-01-2001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting the original question as: "How to make the given main function work?"

Minimal intrusive way, would be

```
istream & operator>>(istream & is, Date & d)
{
   int num = 0;
   is >> num;
   d.incrementMonth(d, num);
   return is;
}
```

Although I want to stress, that this solution results in rather unexpected code (reading an object vs reading an int to increment).

Comment: This worked perfectly. its funny because I tried this same method and passed the parameters d and num and it wouldnt allow it. I think setting the istream as a friend fixed that problem.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using friend. You only need to be friend, if you try changing _month directly.

Comment: I understand now. So what could have the problem be? The error was method was not declared when I tried doing this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The overloaded input operator >> should be declared as friend:

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream & is, Date & d);
```

and defined outside the class block as below:

```
istream & operator>>(istream & is, Date & d)
{
   is >> d.month_; // input the month only
   d.day_ = d.year_ = 0; 
   return is;
}
```

For assigning values for day and year, assign some acceptable default values to make the date object complete while taking input
Now your date object will be take input from one value as desired.
Ok?

Comment: I understand what your saying but whats suppose to happen is the day is suppose to stay the same as the default constructor day, but the year and month are suppose to change accordingly when being passed the month parameter. So if the date was 01-01-2000 (month-day-year) and the user increments it 13 months, then the output should be (02-01-2001). Im not sure how to also pass these parameters to incrementMonth(). Thanks for such a quick reply.

Comment: @mg7 The `d` parameter already contains those parameters, but they're called "member variables".

Comment: @molbdnilo I am confused as to what you are referring to. Can you explain a little further?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
int increment;
cout << "Enter month increment (0 to exit): " << endl;
cin >> increment;
if (increment == 0) {
   // your special exit stuff
}
d.incrementMonth(increment);
```

This way you can do:

1. Exit on 0 as your printed comment suggests
2. Eliminate the first parameter of incrementMonth method. (Use the `this` variable instead.)

Comment: Yes I tried doing this but I have to use that specific function with those exact parameters. It is part of my requirement.